# Searching a list of objects in Python

Tags: python

Let's assume I'm creating a simple class to work similar to a C-style struct, to just hold data elements.  I'm trying to figure out how to search a list of objects for objects with an attribute equaling a certain value.  Below is a trivial example to illustrate what I'm trying to do.

For instance:

```
class Data:
    pass

myList = []

for i in range(20):
    data = Data()
    data.n = i
    data.n_squared = i * i
    myList.append(data)
```

How would I go about searching the myList list to determine if it contains an element with n == 5?

I've been Googling and searching the Python docs, and I think I might be able to do this with a list comprehension, but I'm not sure.  I might add that I'm having to use Python 2.4.3 by the way, so any new gee-whiz 2.6 or 3.x features aren't available to me.

Comment: Perhaps an unintentional quirk of your example: myList = [Data().n==0, Data().n=1, ...] where data.n would be assigned by range() and data.n would be the index into myList. Therefore allowing you to pull up any Data() instance just by referencing myList by an index value. Of course you could later modifiy myList[0].n = 5.2 or something. And the example was perhaps over-simplified.

Answer (score 210, accepted):

You can get a list of *all* matching elements with a list comprehension:

```
[x for x in myList if x.n == 30]  # list of all elements with .n==30
```

If you simply want to determine if the list contains *any* element that matches and do it (relatively) efficiently, you can do

```
def contains(list, filter):
    for x in list:
        if filter(x):
            return True
    return False

if contains(myList, lambda x: x.n == 3)  # True if any element has .n==3
    # do stuff
```

Comment: or, any(custom_filter(x) for x in myList if x.n == 30) which is just your "contains" function as a builtin.

Comment: Syntax error on nosklo -- need an extra set of () around the generator.

Comment: it would be good to merge this answer together with gahooa's (http://stackoverflow.com/a/598602/2349267).

Answer (score 98):

**Simple, Elegant, and Powerful:**

A generator expression in conjuction with a builtin… (python 2.5+)

```
any(x for x in mylist if x.n == 10)
```

Uses the Python [`any()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) builtin, which is defined as follows:

> **any(iterable)** `->` 
>   Return True if any element of the iterable is true. Equivalent to:

```
def any(iterable):
    for element in iterable:
        if element:
            return True
    return False
```

Comment: Nice. FYI you can do any(x for x in mylist if x.n == 10) to save some parens (also == not =).

Comment: I prefer use `any(x for x in mylist if x['n'] == 10)` but is good idea

Comment: Very classy solution. Improves readability too imo.

Answer (score 59):

```
[x for x in myList if x.n == 30]               # list of all matches
[x.n_squared for x in myList if x.n == 30]     # property of matches
any(x.n == 30 for x in myList)                 # if there is any matches
[i for i,x in enumerate(myList) if x.n == 30]  # indices of all matches

def first(iterable, default=None):
  for item in iterable:
    return item
  return default

first(x for x in myList if x.n == 30)          # the first match, if any
```

Comment: This is a good answer because of the "first" method, which is probably the most common use case.

Comment: great, thanks! the match indices was what I was looking for. Is there a shortcut to use this to directly index the list to access another field? Now I get a list of list entries (there is just one entry, so it's a list with one item). To get the index, I need to perform result[0] before I can use it to index the list. From the question example, I want to access n_squared from a particular n: myList[index of myList.n==5].n_squared

Answer (score 58):

Just for completeness, let's not forget the Simplest Thing That Could Possibly Work:

```
for i in list:
  if i.n == 5:
     # do something with it
     print "YAY! Found one!"
```

Answer (score 51):

```
filter(lambda x: x.n == 5, myList)
```

Comment: for someone who wants to learn Python, understanding lambda is basic.

Comment: Well, yes and no -- with list comprehensions and sorting key functions makers like operator.attrgetter, I hardly ever use `lambda`s.

Comment: I like simple 

Answer (score 13):

Another way you could do it is using the next() function.

```
matched_obj = next(x for x in list if x.n == 10)
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use `in` to look for an item in a collection, and a list comprehension to extract the field you are interested in. This (works for lists, sets, tuples, and anything that defines `__contains__` or `__getitem__`).

```
if 5 in [data.n for data in myList]:
    print "Found it"
```

See also:

- [Contains Method](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__)
- [In operation](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#in)

Answer (score 5):

You should add a `__eq__` and a `__hash__` method to your `Data` class, it could check if the `__dict__` attributes are equal (same properties) and then if their values are equal, too.

If you did that, you can use

```
test = Data()
test.n = 5

found = test in myList
```

The `in` keyword checks if `test` is in `myList`.

If you only want to a a `n` property in `Data` you could use:

```
class Data(object):
    __slots__ = ['n']
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n
    def __eq__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, Data):
            return False
        if self.n != other.n:
            return False
        return True
    def __hash__(self):
        return self.n

    myList = [ Data(1), Data(2), Data(3) ]
    Data(2) in myList  #==> True
    Data(5) in myList  #==> False
```

Answer (score 3):

Consider using a dictionary:

```
myDict = {}

for i in range(20):
    myDict[i] = i * i

print(5 in myDict)
```

Comment: Or:
d = dict((i, i*i) for i in range(20))

Comment: It solves the trivial problem I used to illustrate my question, but didn't really solve my root question. The answer I was looking for (5+ years ago) was the list comprehension. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the following list comprehension in combination with the `index` method:

```
data_n = 30
j = [data.n for data in mylist].index(data_n)
print(mylist[j].data.n == data_n)
```

Comment: What does this do if the value's not found?

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised there's no answer that asserts that only one item matches.

Maybe this does that:

```
def one_matching(list, test):
  filtered = [item for item in list if test(item)]
  if len(filtered) != 1:
    if len(filtered) == 0:
      raise KeyError("No matching value found.")
    else:
      raise KeyError("Multiple matching values found.", *filtered)
  return filtered[0] 

# prints 2:
print(one_matching([1,2,3], lambda x: x**2 == 4))
```