# Difference between two "contains" operations for python lists

Tags: python, list, contains

I'm fairly new to python and have found that I need to query a list about whether it contains a certain item.
The majority of the postings I have seen on various websites (including [this similar stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/598398/searching-a-list-of-objects-in-python)) have all suggested something along the lines of

```
for i in list
    if i == thingIAmLookingFor
        return True
```

However, I have also found from one lone forum that

```
if thingIAmLookingFor in list
    # do work
```

works.

I am wondering if the `if thing in list` method is shorthand for the `for i in list` method, or if it is implemented differently.

I would also like to which, if either, is more preferred.

Comment: `thingIAmLookingFor in list` is basically the same as iterating over the list and compare each element. Btw, don't name your variable `list`.

Comment: Oh, so it is implemented with the same code as was suggested. Makes sense since lists aren't ordered. Also, in serious code, I always try to use meaningful names ;-].

Comment: @DanBlakemore - it's implemented that way for lists, perhaps, but almost all other datatypes will implement it more appropriately. For instance, a dict doesn't iterate across all its keys. In this one particular case they happen to work alike. That's just a coincidence.

Comment: @Kirk Strauser, I did follow the __contains__ hint from your other comment and discover that it is implemented for other python containers as well as available to be implemented for custom containers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your simple example it is **of course** better to use `in`.

**However**... in [the question you link to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/598398/searching-a-list-of-objects-in-python), `in` *doesn't work* (at least not directly) because the OP does not want to find an object that is equal to something, but an object whose **attribute `n`** is equal to something.

One [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/598398/searching-a-list-of-objects-in-python/598427#598427) *does* mention using `in` on a list comprehension, though I'm not sure why a generator expression wasn't used instead:

```
if 5 in (data.n for data in myList):
    print "Found it"
```

But this is hardly much of an improvement over the other approaches, such as this one using `any`:

```
if any(data.n == 5 for data in myList):
    print "Found it"
```

Comment: true, there may be some cases where you need the loop. I'm not sure this example is one though.

Comment: The above solution using "any" is idiomatic Python (the one obvious way to do it).  The other solution than runs "in" on a generator expression is atypical and non-pythonic.

Answer (score 2):

the "if x in thing:" format is strongly preferred, not just because it takes less code, but it also works on other data types and is (to me) easier to read.

I'm not sure how it's implemented, but I'd expect it to be quite a lot more efficient on datatypes that are stored in a more searchable form. eg. sets or dictionary keys.

Comment: `foo in bar` in shorthand for `bar.__contains__(foo)`. Any class can define `__contains__` to be an appropriately efficient search. For example, an SQL table wrapper could make `__contains__` execute an indexed database query returning a boolean value so you can search through millions of rows in a few milliseconds.

Comment: With the standard CPython implementation, even on a list it can be expected to be more efficient in a constant-factor sense because the looping can be done internally in the C interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

The `if thing in somelist` is the preferred and fastest way.

Under-the-hood that use of the in-operator translates to `somelist.__contains__(thing)` whose implementation is equivalent to:  `any((x is thing or x == thing) for x in somelist)`.

Note the condition tests identity and then equality.

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in list
    if i == thingIAmLookingFor
        return True
```

The above is a terrible way to test whether an item exists in a collection. It *returns* `True` from the function, so if you need the test as part of some code you'd need to move this into a separate utility function, or add `thingWasFound = False` before the loop and set it to `True` in the if statement (and then break), either of which is several lines of boilerplate for what could be a simple expression.

Plus, if you just use `thingIAmLookingFor in list`, this *might* execute more efficiently by doing fewer Python level operations (it'll need to do the same operations, but maybe in C, as `list` is a builtin type). But even more importantly, if `list` is actually bound to some other collection like a set or a dictionary `thingIAmLookingFor in list` will use the hash lookup mechanism such types support and be *much* more efficient, while using a `for` loop will force Python to go through every item in turn.

**Obligatory post-script:** `list` is a terrible name for a variable that contains a list as it shadows the `list` builtin, which can confuse you or anyone who reads your code. You're much better off naming it something that tells you something about what it *means*.