# Python 3: Check if a List contains an object with specific string value

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, python-2.7

I got this list of strings:

```
json = ['red', 'blue', 'green']
```

and this constant list of Colors:

```
MY_COLORS = [Color('blue', 'www.example.com'), Color('red', 'www.example2.com')]

class Color:
    def __init__(self, name: str, url: str):
        self.name = name
        self.url = url
```

Now I want to check if there is any object within my constant list with a name value that matches any string of my list of strings.
If so I want to return all the matching objects as list to get this result:

```
some_magic(MY_COLORS, json) == [objectred, objectblue]
# no object with name green as its not inside my "MY_COLORS" constant
```

I tried "any" like suggested in [Check if List of Objects contain an object with a certain attribute value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9371114/check-if-list-of-objects-contain-an-object-with-a-certain-attribute-value) but that did not solve the problem oof returning a list of all matching objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do:

```
class Color:
    def __init__(self, name: str, url: str):
        self.name = name
        self.url = url

MY_COLORS = [Color('blue', 'www.example.com'), Color('red', 'www.example2.com')]

json = ['red', 'blue', 'green']
set_json = set(json)

result = [color for color in  MY_COLORS if color.name in set_json]
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

`len([color for color in MY_COLORS if color.name in json]) == 0`
It returns `True` if a color name match one of the color listed in the json variable, `False` otherwise.