# How to change a list from saying true/false for even and odd numbers , to simply saying even or odd for each number?

Tags: python, empty-list

My specifications were:

> - Create an empty list called `to_ten`.
> - Next, write a for loop that iterates over the numbers from 1 to 10 using the `range()` function and appends to the list whether the number is even or odd.
>
> You should end up with a list containing 10 elements with each entry being even or odd.

This is my code:

```
to_ten = []
for x in range(11):
    to_ten.append(x%2==0)
to_ten
```

So far I am getting correctly whether they are even or odd but it is giving me true/false instead of simply saying even/odd for each number in my list.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generating a list of EVEN numbers in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11233355/generating-a-list-of-even-numbers-in-python)

Comment: @Sushanth, that link gives you a list of even numbers, not a list of indications as to whether each number was odd or even.

Comment: that's because you are checking whether or not a condition is True or False or not, so that's what you're getting..you need to add something like - if its odd, append "odd"

Comment: for the sake of fun, two other approaches would be: `['Even' if x%2==0 else 'Odd' for x in range(11)]` or `list(map(lambda x: 'Even' if x%2 == 0 else 'Odd', range(11)))`

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code:

```
to_ten = []
for x in range(11):
    to_ten.append(x%2==0)
to_ten
```

which gives me: `[True, False, True, False, True, False, True, False, True, False, True]`

Now all you want is to have `Even` if it is `True` and `Odd` otherwise

You can use in-line if-else statement as follows

```
to_ten = ["Even" if i else "Odd" for i in to_ten ]
```

```
['Even','Odd','Even','Odd','Even','Odd','Even','Odd','Even','Odd','Even']
```

You can directly do it in your code as well

```
to_ten = []
for x in range(11):
    to_ten.append("Even" if x%2==0 else "Odd")
to_ten
```

> Also you are iterating from 0 to 10 if you want to go from 1 to 10 it is `range(1,11)`

Answer (score 0):

You *almost* have it, you just need to:

- realise that iterating from `1` to `10` involves starting at one; and
- inserting what you want in the list rather than the boolean value.

For example:

```
to_ten = []
for x in range(1, 11):
    to_ten.append('even' if x % 2 == 0 else 'odd')
print(to_ten)
```

That gives:

```
['odd', 'even', 'odd', 'even', 'odd', 'even', 'odd', 'even', 'odd', 'even']
```

---

Of course, the Pythonic way is almost *always* with a list comprehension, though your specifications clearly call for appending to an initially empty list, so I wouldn't use this (it's good to know about it, however):

```
to_ten = ['even' if x % 2 == 0 else 'odd' for x in range(1, 11)]
```