# App engine datastore - searching a list of entities

Tags: google-app-engine

I have pulled a list of entities from my datastore in app engine.  Each entity in the list has a "name" attribute.  Is there a quick way to search the list of entities for a specific name?

As opposed to iterating through each one and checking the name attribute

Thanks!

Comment: are you using `db` or `ndb`? are names unique or are you searching for all entities with that name?

Comment: names will be unique; not sure what you mean by db or ndb

Comment: There are two main GAE datastore access methods- DB and NDB. NDB is the newer one, use this.  If names are unique in your app have a look at get_by_id() which will allow you, if you've used "name" as the ID of the model in the datastore, to retrieve the record directly. More here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/modelclass#Model_get_by_id

Answer (score 1):

You can pull out the entity you are looking for directly if you have an attribute you can match against

```
q = Person.all()
q.filter("name =", target_last_name)
result = q.get()
```

But as far as I know, you have to iterate around the result list if you are not querying against a specific attribute.

This link talks about efficent ways to do that however:

[Searching a list of objects in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/598398/searching-a-list-of-objects-in-python)

E.G.

```
     [x for x in myList if x.n == 30]
```

Comment: is Person a list of entities?

Comment: No, person is the model type and result is the data returned from the datastore. There might be more then one, i.e. a list.